# Shopping cart item gets stored in a different page

Tags: javascript, cart

Hello everyone I have been having trouble getting the shop page to add an item to the shopping cart which is on a different page, the shopping cart works on the same page as the shop, but how do I get it to store on a different page like ebay or amazon for example, they have a separate page for their shopping cart. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

I have tried linking to another page, I have heard someone say use localStorage but I don't know if that will allow a user to add an item that gets stored in the shopping cart. Do I have to implement a little backend for this to work? Thank you

Javascript

```
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready);
} else {
    ready();
}


function ready() {

const removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger');
console.log(removeCartItemButtons);
for (let i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
    button = removeCartItemButtons[i];
button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItems)
}
}

function removeCartItems(event) {
    const buttonClicked = event.target;
    console.log(buttonClicked);
    buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
    updateCartTotal()
}

const quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input');
for (let i = 0; i < quantityInputs; i++) {
    const input = quantityInputs[i]
    input.addEventListener('change', quantityChange)
}

function quantityChange() {
    if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
        input.value = 1;
}
updateCartTotal();
}
// quantityInputs.addEventListener('change', quanti )

const addCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-button');
for (let i = 0; i < addCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
    const addtoCart = addCartItemButtons[i];
    addtoCart.addEventListener('click', addItem)
}

function addItem(event) {
    console.log(event.target);
    const button = event.target;
    const shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement;
    const title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title')[0].innerText;
console.log(title);
    const price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-price')[0].innerText;
    console.log(price)
    const image = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-image')[0].src;
    addItemtoCart(title, price, image)
    updateCartTotal();
}

function addItemtoCart(title, price, image) {
    const cartRow = document.createElement('div');
    // cartRow.append()
    cartRow.classList.add('cart-row');
    cartRow.innerText = title;
    const cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0];
    // var cartItems = localStorage.getItem('cartItems');

    // cartItems.push(newItem);

    // localStorage.setItem('cartItems', cartItems);
    const cartItemsTitle = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title');
    for (let i = 0; i < cartItemsTitle.length; i++) {
        if (cartItemsTitle[i].innerText === title) {
            alert('This item is already in your cart');
            return
}
}
    console.log(cartRow)
console.log(cartItemsTitle)
    cartRowContents = `
                <div class="cart-item cart-column">
             <span class="shop-item-title">${title}</span>
                
                <img  class="blackMug Mugs cart-item-image" src="${image}" alt="">
                
            </div>
            <span class="cart-item-price">${price}</span>
            <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
                <input type="number" class="cart-quantity-input" value="1">
            
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
            </div>`
    cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents;
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-danger')[0].addEventListener('click', removeCartItems);
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0].addEventListener('change', quantityChange)
    cartItems.append(cartRow)
}

function updateCartTotal() {
    const cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0];
    console.log(cartItemContainer)
    const cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row');
    console.log(cartRows)
    let total = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
        const cartRow = cartRows[i];
        const priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-price')[0];
        console.log(priceElement);
        const quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0];
        console.log(quantityElement);
        const price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('$', ''));
        const quantity = quantityElement.value;
        console.log(price * quantity)
        total = total + (price * quantity);
}
        total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100
        document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-price')[0].innerText = '$' + total;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="shop-item">
                <span class="shop-item-title">Grey Sweatshirt</span>
                <img class="greySweater shop-item-image" src="/assets/images/greysweater.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="cart-item-details">
                  <p>Deutschland Autohaus premier sweetshirt (Grey)</p>
                  <span class="shop-item-price">$50</span>
                  <button class="cartBTN btn btn-primary shop-item-button">Add to cart</button>
                </div>
          </div>
              <!-- <div class="cart-item-price">
              <span class="price">$50</span>
              </div> -->
              <!-- <button class="cartBTN">Add to cart</button> -->
            <div class="shop-item">
              <span class="shop-item-title">Black Sweatshirt</span>
              <img class="blackSweater shop-item-image" src="/assets/images/blacksweater.jpg" alt="">
              <div class="cart-item-details">
                  <p>Deutschland Autohaus premier sweetshirt (Black)</p>
                  <span class="shop-item-price">$45</span>
                  <button class="cartBTN btn btn-primary shop-item-button">Add to cart</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="shop-item">
                <span class="shop-item-title">Blue Sweatershirt</span>
                <img class="blueSweater shop-item-image" src="/assets/images/bluesweater.jpg" alt="">
              <div class="cart-item-details">
                  <p>Deutschland Autohaus premier sweetshirt (Blue)</p>
                  <span class="shop-item-price">$50</span>
                  <button class="cartBTN btn btn-primary shop-item-button">Add to cart</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        <!-- </div>     -->
</div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>

<h2>Cart</h2>
<div class="cart-items">
<div class="cart-row">
            <div class="cart-item cart-column">
            <span class="shop-item-title">Black Mugs</span>
                <img class="blackMug Mugs cart-item-image" src="/assets/images/IMG_0444.jpeg" alt="">
                <span class="shop-item-title">Black Mug</span>
            </div>
            <span class="cart-item-price">$29.99</span>
            <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
                <input type="number" class="cart-quantity-input" value="1">
              <p>Deutschland Autohaus premier coffee mug (Black)</p>
              <span class="cart-item-price">$30</span>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
            </div>
        </div>
          <div class="cart-item-price">
          <span >$30</span>
          </div>
          <button class="cartBTN1">Add to cart</button>
          <div class="cart-row">
            <div class="cart-item cart-column">
            <span class="shop-item-title">Red Mug</span>
                <img class="blackMug Mugs cart-item-image" src="/assets/images/IMG_0442.jpeg" alt="">
                <span class="cart-item-title">Black Mugs</span>
            </div>
            <span class="cart-item-price">$29.99</span>
            <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
                <input type="number" class="cart-quantity-input" value="1">
              <p>Deutschland Autohaus premier coffee mug (Black)</p>
              <span class="cart-item-price">$30</span>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
      </div>
        <div class="cart-total">
            <strong class="cart-total-title">Total</strong>
            <span class="cart-total-price">$0</span>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-purchase">PURCHASE</button>
```

Comment: Hey @Jaromanda X how would I implement it?

Comment: How would I use local Storage on two different HTML pages, One for the shop page and the other for the shopping cart itself, If you could give an example I would really appreciate you.

Comment: Yes they are on the same domain, if you mean both pages will link together

Comment: I have both these sites linked together (or should be connected in some way)   http://localhost:3000/deutchlandautohaus/shoppingcart and http://localhost:3000/deutchlandautohaus/shop...When I try and get data from the cart in my shopping cart page it's giving me errors like '[object, object]', and cart.push is not a function.

Comment: So I am wondering how it is possible to retrieve data from the other page so I can add a shopping cart with all the products the user has clicked on. I hope I'm making sense I've been on this for days, so any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you